# Did company decide not to hire me? I told them I have another offer so want a reply soon

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources, contracts, employees

I recently interviewed for a job that I'm really interested in. Had 3 rounds of interview and cleared all of them. HR then asked for references. After contacting the references I listed, HR sent an email on Monday saying they are working on putting together an offer for me and will get back to me by end of the week.

However, I got an offer from another company on Wednesday so requested the first company to let me know if they can let me know if the process is moving forward so that I can decide on how to proceed further. I also made it clear this company is my first preference. HR scheduled a call for next day and said that they are working with lawyers to prepare a contract and it is taking time as they were hiring from a different country and the process is new for them.

We agreed that we would talk again on Monday and she would update me on the status.
Now it is Saturday and I'm still waiting for an update from them. I sent follow up email on Monday and Wednesday but HR haven't replied. So I'm worried that they might have stopped the hiring process because I told I have another offer.

I have 2 more days to accept this new offer but really hoping that the first company will reach out to me. It is my dream job and I was so excited.

Any thoughts on why HR isn't replying to my email? Are they just busy or decided to not offer me the position?

Comment: I would honestly just forget it.  Jobs come and go.  "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush."  Take the job with the firm offer and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess i have to take this job up. It's just that this job is in a different city and I would have to move their while my husband's job is in my current city. It's gonna be tough on personal life. :(

Comment: No one can know the answer to this but the company, and if they are not responding you need to make sure you are not left with zero offers.

Comment: hi @Rachel I can't really imagine a separate city situation, that's tough.  Too bad you can't just find a remote job, there are so many around. Best of luck.

Comment: I can't tell if there's been one week or two since the 2nd offer came in? Has it been 2 days or a whole week since company A went radio silent?

Comment: @Fattie There are many of them around for some industries. Not everybody sits at a desk all day.

Comment: Hi Daniel, 2nd offer came in a week back. I contacted the first company right away and they have been silent one week. I have been stalling to sign the contract for 2nd company but i need to sign it tomorrow.

Comment: What would it cost you to resign from the second company if the first one would finally come through?   Anyway, almost as @Fattie said: better one bird in your hand than ten in the air.

Comment: It would cost one month's gross salary if I quit before starting. Current tentative joining date is june 1st. So I'm thinking of signing the contract and waiting to see if the 1st company responds. I know it is ethically wrong but I'm left with no options.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - you're 10000% correct.  I (stupidly) assumed this is Software Related.  Unfortunately there are just so many software/programmer questions on this site, it is unfortunately an easy mistake to make.  But still my fault.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for us to know what's going on with HR.

What I will tell you is that in my experience, HR processes are slow. And I would also say that the HR process is not always indicative of other areas of the business. (In other words, poor HR performance is not a "red flag" in my opinion). In any case, I'm inclined to believe them that it will take a little while to organise all the paperwork given you're going to be working in a different country.

If you absolutely must have a job in the short term, I would find out when the second company would like an answer. Then I would set a deadline for the first company, and let them know that if you don't receive an offer, you'll be forced to accept the other offer.

If you think you'd be able to easily find another job if both fall through, then it may be worthwhile waiting for them to come through with a contract. I have no idea about your personal situation if it's worth the risk of not having any offers available to you.

Comment: It had already been a week since the 2nd company sent ne contract. i will have to accept it in next 2 days. I have been searching for a job since a very long time so i cant imagine declining the offer i have in the hope of getting something soon. I'm worried about my career as it's been 2.5 years since i was last worked.

Comment: I was in communication with the HR who took my first round of HR interview. Can i contact the HR who was organizing the interviews and ask for an update? Would that be rude considering i was talking with this HR already?

Comment: @Rachel, Be as rude as necessary (and within reason of course), if you're too patient and polite, you're not going to get that second contract offer in time. Actually, do you have the contact of the hiring manager? If the hiring manager really wants you, he may be able to light a fire under the people responsible.

Comment: I can connect to hiring manager on LinkedIn. Is that ok? I'm just worried that I might have pissed them off by saying I have another offer abd don't want to do any further damage

Comment: *HR processes are slow*. And the only thing slower than HR in most companies is legal processes, which may be involved in drawing up a contract. It's definitely true that this can take a long time even in a big company that's otherwise well-run.

Comment: Is it possible to get a confirmation from HR that I'm hired and later get the employment contract in case it's taking time ? Is it safe to turn down the offer i already have before having any written confirmation/ contract from them?

Comment: @Rachel No, it's not safe. Especially if it's a complicated process there can be a few places where they may not be able to deliver a contract where they said they'd be able to.

Comment: I spoke with the HR of company today and she said they are facing some legal challenges with respect to hiring in this country and they went little ahead without realizing the entire process. I guess I'll have to take up the other offer now. Thanks everyone for your suggestions in this. It was really helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The first company agreed to have a contract for you by Friday (I'm assuming you meant May 14, 2021).  As of this writing, it's Sunday, May 16, 2021.  The company has already slipped on carrying out its own proposal to you re an official offer letter.  Since they've had enough time already to do three interviews with you (AND prepare to hire someone from a different country) but now are tripping on themselves, this is a red flag.

Take the other job.  Don't bother contacting the other folks, even though informing them that you've accepted another offer is sure to get their attention if they were serious about you at all.